# How to disable panel cache for user menu?

Tags: 7, panels, caching

I have a panel page and this page is front-page of my site. This page is not for anonymous users and having a user menu with welcome message like.
Welcome [Username], then other user related menus.

But sometime it shows wrong welcome user name. For example there is two users UserA and UserB. 
First time UserA logins into site and it shows "Welcome UserA" after logout UserA other user UserB logs in to the site then welcome message is stills showing with UserA which is not correct.

This is may be due to Drupal cache because when I clear the all cache then it shows the Welcome message for UserB.

I have set the **nocache** from the panels pan setting for user menu.

How can I disable the cache for that page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has a lot of caching levels so you might need to "peel" each one off to know which level is caching the results. Since you're authenticated, it's not the page cache. And since you mentioned that you set the panel to "No Cache", then it's not the panel cache either.

You're probably facing the block cache here. You can either modify the block caching definition in code using [`hook_block_info_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7.x) (see [`hook_block_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7.x) for the different caching levels), or use [Block Cache Alter](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter) module to do that same thing via the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have installed the panels_page_cache module. 
If so, you should go to the panel edition and delete the cache as shown in the image.

[image]